# Laravel storage:link not working on remote server

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel `php artisan storage:link` not working on remote server. Locally all working perfectly.

This is my config/filesystems.php

```
  'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],

],

'links' => [
    public_path('/icons/') => storage_path('app/public/avatars/'),
    
],
```

On hosting, files are uploaded in folder storage perfectly, but not appear in folder public/icons.
I try to fix that and run command: php artisan storage:link on remote server and get response:

The [public/icons/] link already exists.

After that, I removed public/icons/ folder and run command:php artisan storage:link again and get response:

> In Filesystem.php line 335  symlink(): No such file or directory

Any ideas how to fix that?

PS:

1. Site is located on domain: app.mydomain.com.
2. My laravel site located inside public_html/app
3. In env: APP_URL=https://app.mydomain.com
4. Permission of folder public/icons is 755.

Comment: first, confirm that the directory exists on this storage path `app/public/avatars/`. This error generally occurs if the directory you are trying to symlink does not exist if the avatars folder does not exists then create that folder first

Comment: You shouldn't remove `public/icons` folder, get it back and remove the `link` to that folder before creating new one

Comment: I confirm that folder app/public/avatars/ is existing.